# How to get the object name from GET method of IWbemClassObject class in wmi queries?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wmi, wmi-query

My code is following. I am not able to get the permission on repository.

```
int CWmiQueries::InitWmiQueries()
{
HRESULT hres;
hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. " 
        << "Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    return 1;              // Program has failed.
}

// Initialize 
hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,     
    -1,      // COM negotiates service                  
    NULL,    // Authentication services
    NULL,    // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,    // authentication
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // Impersonation
    NULL,             // Authentication info 
    EOAC_NONE,        // Additional capabilities
    NULL              // Reserved
    );


if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize security. " 
        << "Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;          // Program has failed.
}

// Obtain the initial locator to Windows Management
// on a particular host computer.
IWbemLocator *pLoc = 0;

hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,             
    0, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. "
        << "Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;       // Program has failed.
}

IWbemServices *pSvc = 0;

// Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with the
// current user and obtain pointer pSvc
// to make IWbemServices calls.

hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(

    _bstr_t(L"root\\VisualSVN"), // WMI namespace
    NULL,                    // User name
    NULL,                    // User password
    0,                       // Locale
    NULL,                    // Security flags                 
    0,                       // Authority       
    0,                       // Context object
    &pSvc                    // IWbemServices proxy
    );                              

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                // Program has failed.
}

cout << "Connected to ROOT\\VisualSVN WMI namespace" << endl;

// Set the IWbemServices proxy so that impersonation
// of the user (client) occurs.
hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(

   pSvc,                         // the proxy to set
   RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,            // authentication service
   RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,             // authorization service
   NULL,                         // Server principal name
   RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,       // authentication level
   RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // impersonation level
   NULL,                         // client identity 
   EOAC_NONE                     // proxy capabilities     
);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}


// Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI. 
// Make requests here:

// For example, query for all the running processes
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM VisualSVN_SecurityDescriptor"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for processes failed. "
         << "Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}
else
{ 
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {

        hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

    VARIANT vtProp;
SAFEARRAY *psaNames = NULL; 
CIMTYPE type;
LONG flavor;

    hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Permissions", 0, &vtProp, &type, &flavor);
```

**//Get methods returing array of object in VARIANT vtProp. But I am not able to get this object any idea? I have tried but not able to find the object name.**

```
SAFEARRAY *pSafeArray = vtProp.parray; 
UINT lDim = SafeArrayGetDim(pSafeArray);

long lLbound = 0;
long lUbound = 0;
SafeArrayGetLBound(pSafeArray, 1, &lLbound);
SafeArrayGetUBound(pSafeArray, 1, &lUbound);
long lDim3Size = lUbound - lLbound + 1;

for (long k = 0; k < lDim3Size; k++)
{
   char* PropName1;
   hres = SafeArrayGetElement(
            pSafeArray, 
            &k, 
            &PropName1);

 wcout << PropName1<< endl;
    SysFreeString(PropName);
  }

   VariantClear(&vtProp);
    }

}

// Cleanup
// ========

pSvc->Release();
pLoc->Release();     
CoUninitialize();
getchar();
return 0;   // Program successfully completed.
```

}

My question in bold section. Any way to get the object name from variant.